# Getting SQL Server query results into a Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sql-server

OK.  Relatively new at this, but here goes:

I'm trying to get a fairly simple SELECT SQL Server query:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [SeriesType], [Title] 
    FROM [allinfo] WHERE ([SeriesType] = @SeriesType)"
```

Into a javascript array

```
var IssueID = [*/fill me with [ID]s from the above query*/];
```

to then be appended into a Contentflow JS carousel.

The part from the array to the carousel works flawlessly. I can manually fill the array with any number and/or series of numbers, which then appear on the carousel. For some reason, I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the process of getting the query results from the server mssql to the client side JS array. I've looked up and down at AJAX, JSON, Node js--looked through a tonne of questions on the matter, but most look like they're trying to do something different; even looked at trying to address a .NET control from the js. Can't seem to figure out the path from the query result to the js array.

JSON,AJAX,PHP--now I know why insane people laugh a lot..

Comment: So you are trying to access a Microsoft SQL Server from a client side javascript that runs somewhere in a browser?

Comment: Exactly. I'm pretty sure it's possible, and I know I should be able to get that data to where I can push() it into the array, but just can't figure out the steps:  Is it:
SQL to
PHP to
JSON to
JS?

Comment: SQL -> PHP -> JSON -> JS sounds about right, but it depends if your webserver supports PHP or not.

Comment: which server side language are you using or feel comfortable?  this requieres one

Comment: Everything I'm doing serverside (so far)is ASP.net on MS VStudio

Comment: What version of ASP.net and are you using web forms, mvc, webapi?

Comment: All the serverside stuff works as well--I can do what I want with the data when I get it back;  just getting stuck getting it to the clientside

Comment: Right now, just ASP 2.0 without web forms:  basically drag and drop datasource and controls

Comment: You just create an action on a controller in asp.net that returns a serialized list or array and then call that rest action from your javascript.

Comment: ASP.Net 2.0? That came out 10 years ago. Are you sure about the version?

Comment: Yep.  I have just the one application on the server, created about 5-6 years ago.  Up until now, it was just a drag and drop web interface for my SQL database; I recently decided to redo the frontend to a carousel and am trying to learn where I need to go to accomplish

Comment: The following article contains more or less all the relevant steps you need to do to get it done: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45275/Create-a-JSON-WebService-in-ASP-NET-with-a-jQu